# How can I change the distance of tips of \tkzAxeXY?

Tags: tkz-euclide, tkz-collection

I am currently trying to improve the image [de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:TrigEinheitskreis.png](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:TrigEinheitskreis.png) / create a free version of it.

### LaTeX

This is what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, decorations}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,font=\sansmath\sffamily,x=3cm,y=3cm]
    \tkzInit[xmax=1.0,ymax=1.0,xmin=-1.0,ymin=-1.0]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY

    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint({cos(FPpi/5)*1},0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint({cos(FPpi/5)*1},{sin(FPpi/5)*1}){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){CircleEnd}

    \tkzDrawCircle(A,CircleEnd)

    % \tkzLabelPoints[below left,font=\sansmath\sffamily](A)
    % \tkzLabelPoints[below right,font=\sansmath\sffamily](B)

    % Mark angle
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.6cm,fill=green!30](B,A,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.15](B,A,C){$\alpha$}

    % Draw polygon
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[black!60!green,very thick](A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[red,very thick](B,C)

    % Label lines
    \tkzLabelSegment[above](A,C){$1$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[sloped,above=-0.05,red](B,C){$\sin(\alpha)$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[below,black!60!green](A,B){$\cos(\alpha)$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

### Rendered

[image]

### Question

I don't like how far the tips of the x-axis and the y-axis are away. How can I change that?

Comment: Feel free to add more changes if you think it improves the image. For example, improving the endings of the colored lines.

Comment: The improved version is now available: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Triangle-unit-circle.svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the options `[up space=y,right space=x]` to `\tkzAxeXY`. `x` and `y` should (apparently) be unitless numbers, and denotes the length, in centimeters, that the axis lines extend beyond the max. As I understand it.

The style of the ticklabels can be modified with the `label options` key for `\tkzAxeXY`, so `label options={fill=none}` will remove the fill.

This is documented in the manual for `tkz-base`, in section 6, *Macros pour les axes*. Note that `\tkzAxeXY` is a combination of the four macros `\tkzDrawX\tkzDrawY \tkzLabelX\tkzLabelY`, so if you look through section 6 and find the description of those four, you'll know which options you can use for the axes. The manual is in French, so knowing that language is an advantage, though you can come a long way by looking at examples, and the fact that the key names are in English. (I don't read French.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, decorations}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,font=\sansmath\sffamily,x=3cm,y=3cm]
    \tkzInit[xmax=1.0,ymax=1.0,xmin=-1.0,ymin=-1.0]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY[up space=0.2,right space=0.2, label options={fill=none}]

    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint({cos(FPpi/5)*1},0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint({cos(FPpi/5)*1},{sin(FPpi/5)*1}){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){CircleEnd}

    \tkzDrawCircle(A,CircleEnd)

    % \tkzLabelPoints[below left,font=\sansmath\sffamily](A)
    % \tkzLabelPoints[below right,font=\sansmath\sffamily](B)

    % Mark angle
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.6cm,fill=green!30](B,A,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.15](B,A,C){$\alpha$}

    % Draw polygon
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[black!60!green,very thick](A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[red,very thick](B,C)

    % Label lines
    \tkzLabelSegment[above](A,C){$1$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[sloped,above=-0.05,red](B,C){$\sin(\alpha)$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[below,black!60!green](A,B){$\cos(\alpha)$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for noting `tkz-base`. I've looked in `tikz` for it. I've just noted that the labels for the units get a white background. Is it possible to get rid of that?

Comment: @moose All `\tkz...` commands are defined by one of the `\tkz` packages, so you won't find any mention of those in `pgfmanual.pdf`. Will have a look at the label stuff.

Comment: @moose Updated answer with `label options={..}`.

Answer (score 0):

With only `tikz`

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, decorations}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,font=\sansmath\sffamily,x=3cm,y=3cm]
  \coordinate[label={below left:0}] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (30:1);
  \coordinate (c) at (1,0);

  \draw [help lines] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);  
  \draw[-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,1.2)node[left]{$y$};  
  \path pic[draw=black,fill=green!30, angle radius=10mm,"$\alpha$",angle eccentricity=0.7] 
                                    {angle = c--A--B};  
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \draw[red] (B) -- ($(A)!(B)!(c)$) node[pos=0.5,above=0.13cm,rotate=180,sloped]{$\sin(\alpha)$}
                                    coordinate (C);
  \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (1.2,0)node[below]{$x$};
  \draw[black!60!green] (A) -- (C)node[pos=0.5,below]{$\cos(\alpha)$};

  \draw circle (1);
  \node [anchor=north east] at (-1,0) {$-1$}; 
  \node [anchor=north west] at (1,0) {$1$};
  \node [anchor=north east] at (0,-1) {$-1$}; 
  \node [anchor=south east] at (0,1) {$1$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]